# Set Async Date to NgbDatePicker ngModel

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I use ngbDatePicker for my angular project. It couldnt set async date to ngModel.

```
        <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="departureDate | async" (click)="dp.toggle()"
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker" [navigation]="navigation"
            [minDate]="minDate">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

How can I set async date to ngbDatepicker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would set a different property and not use the `async` pipe.

```
departureDateValue: string;
ngOnInit() {
  this.departureDate.subscribe(date = > this.departureDateValue = date);
}
```

```
 <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="departureDateValue" (click)="dp.toggle()"
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker" [navigation]="navigation"
            [minDate]="minDate">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

This way `departureDateValue` will have the binding.